# Trying to hide field in New/Edit form of Sharepoint list based on currently logged in user belonging to a Sharepoint group

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Using Sharepoint online. I am using following code to hide fields through JS:

```
<!-- jQuery Reference. You can refer it from Layouts Folder/Doc Library too, after uploading the script. -->
<script src="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Download SPServices from: http://spservices.codeplex.com/ Or use this CDN  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
  async: false,
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
  debugger;
  //If the current User does belong to the group "Service desk Operators"
    if (($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='tecxperts']").length == -1))
     {
     debugger;
          //   alert("No, User Doesn't Exists!");                  
           $("select[title='Project']").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
          $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Project")').parent().hide();
          $('nobr:contains("Project")').closest('tr').hide();
       }
    else{
    debugger;      
        }
 });
});
</script>
```

The `IF` condition always fails although Sharepoint group *tecxperts* exists. This is quite old post however I don't see why it is not working.

I have also tried putting the code in webpart (script editor) and directly into form through SP Designer. Is there any other way to hide field based on user belonging to SP group

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? You can edit newform.aspx and editform.aspx using SharePoint designer or text editor?

Comment: Sharepoint Online

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below snippet it works well  i have replaced the find with string search

```js
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
      userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
      async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
      console.log(xData) 

    if(xData.status == 200) {
      var soapString = xData.responseText 
      var find = soapString.search("tecxperts")
      if(find == -1){
       alert("user not found in the group")
      } 
     else{
         alert("userfound in the group")
       }
    }
  }
     
});
    });
    </script>
```

Please up vote if accepted

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

if the current User does belong to the group "tecxperts", it won't enter following code:

```
if (($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='tecxperts']").length == -1))
 {
 debugger;
      //   alert("No, User Doesn't Exists!");                  
       $("select[title='Project']").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
      $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Project")').parent().hide();
      $('nobr:contains("Project")').closest('tr').hide();
   }
```

You may need to change the condition like below:

```
($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='tecxperts']").length != -1
```

reference code:
[Hide Fields using Permission Levels in SharePoint using Java Script](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/807324/Hide-Fields-using-Permission-Levels-in-SharePoint)

[SHAREPOINT – USE JQUERY TO HIDE COLUMNS BASED ON A USERS GROUP MEMBERSHIP](https://theezitguy.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/sharepoint-use-jquery-to-hide-columns-based-on-a-users-group-membership/)

thanks